# How can I add a "Select All" option to a jqGrid select toolbar filter?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm building tables using jqGrid with a filter toolbar to let users filter the rows displayed in the table. This is all working nicely if I use text as the search type, but for some columns I want to use a select list to make it easier for users to filter based on the values in the column.

I can set the column stype to "select", and populate the options using the values in my table, and everything works nicely. However, if I add another option with a value of "all" (so that the user can display rows with any value in that column) it appears in the select list as "Undefined".

The colModel definition for an example column is

```
  {name:'keyword',
    index:'keyword',
    width:150, 
    align:'left',
    stype:'select',
    sortable:true,
    searchoptions: { value: '"",All;keyword 1,keyword 1;keyword 2,keyword 2' } },
```

As an additional example, I have another column which displays true or false. In order to make my table look nice, I'm displaying either a nice green tick image, or a red cross image. I want the select box to contain "All", "Yes" or "No". However, as none of the rows in the table have these values, the select list contains "Undefined" three times.

Is there some way I can force the select list to display my select options, even though they don't exist in the table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doh! Pilot error.

The values have to be in the form

```
value:text;value:text;value:text
```

I was using

```
value,text;value,text;value,text
```

It's all in the detail...