# how to add checkbox in the jqgrid filter search tool bar?

Tags: jqgrid

In the jqgrid filter toolbar textbox search is working perfectly.. i want to include the checkboxes instead of textbox for search.

how to create? plz explain me..

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3):

In the filter toolbar you should better use **select** element with **three values**: "checked" , "unchecked"  and "no filter" (see [How can I add a "Select All" option to a jqGrid select toolbar filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167179/how-can-i-add-a-select-all-option-to-a-jqgrid-select-toolbar-filter)). Of cause you should choose the texts which better corresponds the contain or the name of the column. If you will have only **two values** like the checkbox has, that you will always have filtering on the column with the checkbox.

Comment: i want to include the staff names in the checkboxes. more than 15 checkboxes will be display there. depends on the checkbox selection data will be filter. checkbox selection may be single or multiple. moreover checkbox values will display from Array. Is it possible in JQGRID? thanks....

Answer (score 2):

**Jqgrid Search toolbar**

**There is no option for adding check box in Search toolbar** , but we can add a column with values as check box in grid rows

**Alternative way :**

```
 It contains the following options for common searching
```

**search,stype,searchoptions,searchrules**

**stype :**

- It determines the search type of the field. (text and select)

**text:** create the text element in search toolbar

**select:** create the select(drop down) element in search toolbar

Example:

I have a grid with the column name **system_defined** , I want to show the checkbox in each grid row and search toolbar will be shown as a drop down values with multiselect option.

{name:'system_defined',index:'system_defined', edittype:'checkbox', search: true, formatter: "checkbox", editoptions: { value: "1:Yes;0:No"},editable:true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'], value: ":All;1:Yes;0:No" }, stype: 'select'}